# fetch() POST request to Express generates empty body {}

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch, body-parser

My code :

1. react.js

   ```
   let lsStr = ''
   lsStr = `https://192.168.0.1/basic/code02/exlup02`
   if (window.confirm(message)) {    
       fetch(lsStr,
       {  method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({"Data": "MY DATA"}),
          headers:{
             'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
        })
        .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
        .then(data =>console.log(data));
   ```

2.server.js

```
    var express  = require('express')
    var router = express.Router();
    const cors = require('cors')
    var pool = require('../db')  

    router.post('/code02/exlup02', function(req, res, next) {
            console.log('post page')  
            let lsModnm = req.body;

            if(!lsModnm){
              return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide excel' });
            }else{
               console.log(req.body)  
            }   
    });
```

Currently: console.log(req.body) logs {}

```
      return message : Please provide excel!!
```

Desired: console.log(req.body) logs "MY DATA"

Can't solve it with router?

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Why aren’t you sending data in the else statement?

Answer (score 10):

Solved the problem

1.react.js

fixed

```
    headers:{          
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```

2.server.js

add

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

consol.log

```
post page  
[ { modnm: 'test1', remark: 1, useyn: 're1' },
  { modnm: 'test2', remark: 1, useyn: 're2' },
  { modnm: 'test3', remark: 1, useyn: 're3' },
  { modnm: 'test4', remark: 1, useyn: 're4' },
  { modnm: 'test5', remark: 1, useyn: 're5' } ]
```